# applying specific theme to particular form in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I wanted to add a specific theme for particular form in Drupal. for example lets say that I want to apply a  template named menu_edit.tpl.php to menu_edit_menu form. How can this be done. Can this be implemented using Hook_theme() function. Can anyone provide me code snippet on how to do this. Any help on this regards will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using `template` key in hook_theme

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_theme().
*/
function yourmodule_theme() {
  return array(
   'variables' => array(1) , 
   'template' =>  'my_template' , 
  ) ; 
}
```

in this example you can create `my_template.tpl.php` in the same module directory

[follow this tutorial for more details](http://drupal.org/node/1092122)

Good luck

Comment: Thank u very much. I was looking for this solution for long time.. This worked well.. but can u explain me why we use 'Variables' ?

Comment: you can change this name anyway, but this name should be the same as the name that passed from the parameter E.g `function template_preprocess_article_node_form(&$vars)` in this case you should use `$vars` instead of `$variables`